# Parsing a String to construct a Tree in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, stack, adt

I have no idea what direction to take with this - I'm trying to parse an expression "(4 + 3)", and build a Tree from it. However, In my EvalExp method I have no idea what to do from here. The ordering for the expression should be value/operator/value/operator so I've put in 2 stacks, to identify either. Any ideas what I should do next?

```
public class Tree {

    class ExprTreeNode {

        ExprTreeNode left, right;
        boolean isLeaf;
        int value;
        char op;

        public ExprTreeNode(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.op = op;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }


    }

    private Stack opStk = new Stack();
    private Stack valStk = new Stack();
    private ExprTreeNode root;


    public Tree(String s) {

        root = (ExprTreeNode) EvalExp(s);
    }

    public Object EvalExp(String str) {

        Scanner s = null;

        try {
            s = new Scanner(str);

            while (s.hasNext()) {

                // push to val stk
                if (s.hasNextInt()) {   
                    valStk.push(s.next());
                } else {
                    opStk.push(s.next());
                }

            }

        } finally {

            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }

        //return the root node
        return valStk.peek();
    }
```

Comment: try to read about Reverse Polish notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: I had a look at that and ShuntingYard algorithm but i get stuck so quickly

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a recursive descent parser instead of explicit stacks? Should be something along the lines of

```
static ExprTreeNode parseExpr(Scanner s) {
  ExprTreeNode left = parsePrimary(s);
  if (s.hasNext("\\+")) {
    s.next("\\+");
    ExprTreeNode right = parseExpr(s);
    return new ExprTreeNode('+', left, right);
  }
  return left;
}

public static ExprTreeNode parsePrimary(Scanner s) {
  return new ExprTreeNode(parseNextInt());
}
```